# Setting data attribute to a node in jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have implemented JStree in my project. In certain operation I want to set data attribute in the current selected node .I have tried this. but data attribute is not updating.

```
function SetData(obj)
    {
        debugger;
        var jdata = $('#leftpane').jstree().get_selected(true);
        var key = $('#Key').val();
        var operator = $('#operator').val();
        var value = $('#value').val();

        var newdata = {};
        newdata.key = key;
        newdata.operator = operator;
        newdata.value = value;
        $('#leftpane').jstree().get_selected(true).data = JSON.stringify(newdata);

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Try refreshing the tree after making an update `$('#leftpane').jstree(true).refresh();`

Comment: `.get_selected ()` returns `Array`

Answer (score 1):

You could try ...

```
var arrayOfSelectedNodes = $('#leftpane').jstree().get_selected(true);
$(arrayOfSelectedNodes).data(newdata);

// or, avoiding the assignment
$($('#leftpane').jstree().get_selected(true)).data(newdata);
```

... which will set `newdata` against however many nodes in the tree were selected (none, one, more than one).

In all pobability, you don't need to `JSON.stringify()` as `jQuery.data()` is implemented wholly in javascript, not the DOM, and unstringified objects can be reliably written/read.

You would choose to `JSON.stringify()` if you needed a "snapshot" of an object that is liable to subsequent change.